# How to get all groups which user belong to using Directory Services LDAP?

Tags: .net

I using DirectoryService and query LDAP to get the group names that the user belong to
Suppose i am inside a group "Test100" and this group "Test100" is inside another group say "Test"
when i query the LDAP server the "Test" is not getting returned since it is inside Test100 and i am inside Test100

How to solve this issue.. please help

```
 Dim LDAPpath As String = <LDAP String>
        entry = New DirectoryEntry(LDAPpath, <App ID>, <Password>)
        Dim search As New DirectorySearcher(entry)

        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add([property])
        search.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" & FilterOutDomain(userName)

        Dim result As SearchResult = search.FindOne()




        Return result
```

Comment: What are you currently trying (code)? Also, does this need to be recursive – include groups membership in other groups?

Comment: Added the code this works fine and returns the main group..
For example if i query with my name and if i belong to Test and Test is within another group Test01.. then i am not returned with Test

Answer (score 0):

Using Active Directory as the LDAP provider, this works (at least on a small scale – I've not tested with a large directory):

```cs
class Program {
    HashSet<string> foundGroups = new HashSet<string>();
    Queue<string> toProcess = new Queue<string>();

    void Run(string startingPoint) {

        ExpandMembership(startingPoint);

        while (toProcess.Count > 0) {
            var name = toProcess.Dequeue();
            if (foundGroups.Contains(name)) {
                // Have already handled this group
                continue;
            }

            foundGroups.Add(name);
            ExpandMembership(name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} groups:", foundGroups.Count);
        foreach (var group in foundGroups.OrderBy(s => s)) {
            Console.WriteLine(group);
        }
    }

    private void ExpandMembership(string name) {
        var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + name);
        var memberOf = entry.Properties["memberOf"];
        foreach (string groupName in memberOf) {
            toProcess.Enqueue(groupName);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var userPath = "CN=User Name,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=net";
        var p = new Program();
        p.Run(userPath);

    }
}
```

NB.

1. This will not find "Domain Users", membership of which is implicit and hardcoded into AD rather than being part of each user's attributes.
2. Use of a `Queue` to avoid recursion.
3. Use of a `HashSet` to avoid processing the same  group again, otherwise if A belongs to B, and B belongs to A would lead to an infinite loop.